# Writing HTML Form values in pdf file using PHP

Tags: php

```
<form>
Last Name
<input name="lastname" type="text"/><br/>
First Name
<input name="firstname" type="text"/><br/>
Middle Name
<input name="middlename" type="text"/><br/>
</form>
```

**How do I write all this html form values in following pdf file using php**

I know there are so many php libraries for this but my pdf file so much complicated 
i.e for storing suppose first name of HTML form to pdf I have so many small small text boxes in pdf 
but In HTML form I have only one text box for first name.
How should I do that.

This is the sample pdf image

[image: sample pdf]
http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4793/testpdf.jpg

Comment: have you done any research? got a _specific_ problem? Or do you just want teh codez?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use one of the PHP PDF libraries. FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) will probably do everything you need and it has the benefit of not being a compiled extension.

Whichever library you use, it is likely to have its own documentation and reference resources.

Comment: Why is this a benefit? From an extension standpoint it might, but from a performance standpoint it's not.

Comment: @inquam Realistically? Because you don't need to worry about your hosting company's preferences in installing it or not. After that there is something to be said about a library built in the same language as everything else, but that is a nice-to-have.

Comment: Hosting company? :)... Host your own stuff or at least rent a VM server or dedicated server... full control ftw ;)

To be honest, hosting companies limitations on most "normal" plans is enough to drive any man insane.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions for writing PDF files from PHP. The one that I know best is called [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

The reasons I recommend it are:

- It's open source
- It's in active development and gets regular updates
- It's very feature-rich

But as I say, there are other options, several of which have been suggested by others here. You'll need to investigate them all and find out which best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mention you need to use a PDF library.

I personally prefer http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html

Answer (score 0):

Use one of several existing PDF libraries or one of several existing webservices

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution
I have used createFDF library from following site,
http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/